# Long answer heartbeats from Node.js client when posting

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Faced the problem of **heartbeats** failures from the **Node.js** client (npm-package **amqplib**) when publishing **>150k** unique messages of **20** characters each.

I am sending messages in a loop with the following code:

```
// Publication message
function publish(ch, exchange, routing_key, content, callback_publish) {
    let result = false;
    const message = content.toString();
    try {
        // Trying to publishing message
        ch.publish(exchange, routing_key, content, {persistent: true},
                (err, ok) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('[AMQP] Error publishing message:', err);
                    } else {
                        result = true;
                    }
                    callback_publish(result, message);
                });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('[AMQP] Posting exception message:', e.message);
        callback_publish(result, message);
    }
}

// ch = ...
// exchange = ...
// routing_key = ...

// Receive messages to send
const msgs = messages.get_publisher_messages_to_send()

let j = 1;

// Sending messages
for (let i = 0; i < count_messages; i++) {

    const msg = msgs[i];
    const content = Buffer.from(msg);

    console.log('[AMQP] Message sending:', msg, '(', i + 1,')');

    publish(ch, exchange, routing_key, content, (res, msg) => {
        console.log('[AMQP] Result of sending', res, 'for message:', msg, '(', j, ')');
        j++;
    });

}
```

An example of continuous publication of **100k** messages:

[image: send 100k messages]

On the graph, we see small dips that fit in the interval **heartbeats = 60s**.

But as soon as the volume of messages increases, for example, to **500k** messages, the length of the "step" also increases and the value of **heartbeats = 60s** becomes insufficient. In the **RabbitMQ** logs, a message of the form appears:

> 2020-05-22 10:34:36.975 [error] <0.24252.1> closing AMQP connection
>   <0.24252.1> (192.168.56.25:58446 -> 192.168.56.17:5672): missed
>   heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s

We see that if **RabbitMQ** sends a heartbeat to the client application, if it does not respond, **RabbitMQ** disconnects it.

After looking for information in the [official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html) and on the Internet, you can find two solutions:

1. Set the value of **heartbeats = 0**, thereby disabling the heartbeat
2. Increase the value of **heartbeats** to a higher value, e.g. **heartbeats = 1800s**

I did not like the first option in that by disabling **heartbeats** the client application does not know in a timely manner about the inaccessibility of **RabbitMQ** and this will create a significant risk for data security, especially for publishers.

The second option is also not entirely clear. Increase by how much? If we increase, **heartbeats**, say, up to **1800s** it will work, for example, to send **500k** messages in **20** characters. And if there is a larger amount of data?

Here is an example of publication **500k** messages at a time when **heartbeats = 1800s**:

[image: send 500k messages]

We see that downtime intervals have increased significantly.

Let's increase the volume of transmitted messages even to **1000k**:

[image: send 1000k messages 1 hours]

[image: send 1000k messages 8 hours]

We see that downtime has increased even more.

Are there any other solutions for the **Node.js** client application to “sniff” (the client and server respond to each other via the bidirectional RPC protocol cleaning up in the interval of 60 seconds) with **RabbitMQ**?